# Is it possible to Serialize single item or tree from Sitecore CMS using Sitecore CLI

Tags: serialization, sitecore-cli

We are using `Sitecore CLI` as our serialization tool and we are trying to serialize Sitecore Items on the Item level under the Developer tab in Ribbon.

[image]

We are trying to replicate how `Unicorn` Serializes and Deserializes Items on Item Level from CMS.

Is it possible to serialize and deserialize?

1. single item on click of `Serialize Item or Update Item`
2. tree on click of `Serialize Tree or Update Tree`

When we are using Sitecore CLI on our site?

Comment: 'Serialize Item' executes 'itemsync:dumpitem' command and afaik, Unicorn patches this with its custom implementation to make it work. And I don't see anything similar with SCS. So I doubt that would work without any customization. Check this Unicorn's implementation for reference - https://github.com/SitecoreUnicorn/Unicorn/blob/master/src/Unicorn/UI/Commands/UnicornDumpItemCommand.cs . You will need similar command implementation for SCS

Comment: https://www.koenheye.be/sitecore-10-new-serialization-option/ This article might help

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it should be possible. Sitecore Content Serialization has a `scope` property where it can have any of the following values:

- SingleItem
- ItemAndChildren
- ItemAndDescendants
- DescendantsOnly

So in your *.module.json configuration file, you can have

```
{
  "namespace": "Sitecore.DevEx.NuGetResourcesExample",
  "description": "Content serialization example",
  "items": {
    "includes": [
      {
        "name": "Content",
        "path": "/sitecore/content/home"
        "scope": "SingleItem"
      }
    ]
  }
}
```